# Python: Regular expression to get price from string error

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to make syre everything but numeric values and the decimal point are left in.

**String**

```
[\n\t\t€249.99\xa0\n\t\t\t]
```

**Code**

```
str(re.compile("^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$", PRICE[0]))
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getPrice.py", line 59, in <module>
    JSON_FILE.write("{\"price\":\"" + str(re.compile("^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$", PRICE[0])) + "\"},")
  File "C:\...\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 856, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, False)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' and 'int'
```

Comment: `str(re.compile("^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$", str(PRICE[0])))`

Comment: that should be something along the lines of: `re.match(expression, inputstring)` or `pattern = re.compile(expression)` `pattern.match(inputstring)` for parsing. Though it seem from the error log that you want to write formatted text, which has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: If your strings are always in this format, you may just use `PRICE[0][1:-1].strip()[1:]`. Or remove all but digits and `.` - `re.sub(r'[^0-9.]+', '', PRICE[0])` (this can also be translated to a non-regex solution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are incorrectly using `re.compile`. Here is a solution using `re.search`:

```
s = '\n\t\t€249.99\xa0\n\t\t\t'
re.search('[0-9.]+', s).group()   # Returns '249.99'
```

You can also achieve the same results using `re.findall`, `re.match` or `re.sub`.

Comment: The "\" before the "." is unneeded. Otherwise, a great answer. It should read
're.search('[0-9.]+', s).group()'